# select multiple items from listview and do action on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview, I want to select multiple items from the listview and on button click need to do some action on the rows selected.But I couldn't get the value item from the listview, below is the code I tried, where I'm doing wrong here?

Markup

```
<asp:ListView ID="LvOrders" runat="server" 
    GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1" 
    ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1"
    OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChanging">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="product-master" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th><asp:CheckBox ID="ChkBox" runat="server" /></th>
                <th>Order #</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Purchase Date</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">

                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" 
                        class="btn-group btn-group-sm" 
                        PagedControlID="LvOrders" 
                        PageSize="10">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField PreviousPageText="<" 
                                FirstPageText="|<" 
                                ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                                ShowFirstPageButton="true" 
                                ShowNextPageButton="false" 
                                ShowLastPageButton="false"
                                ButtonCssClass="btn btn-default" 
                                RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="false" 
                                RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="false" />
                            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" 
                                CurrentPageLabelCssClass="btn btn-primary disabled" 
                                RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="false"
                                NumericButtonCssClass="btn btn-default" 
                                ButtonCount="10" 
                                NextPageText="..." 
                                NextPreviousButtonCssClass="btn btn-default" />
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField NextPageText=">" 
                                LastPageText=">|" 
                                ShowNextPageButton="true"
                                ShowLastPageButton="true" 
                                ShowPreviousPageButton="false" 
                                ShowFirstPageButton="false"
                                ButtonCssClass="btn btn-default" 
                                RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="false" 
                                RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="false" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1">
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td><asp:CheckBox ID="ChkBx" runat="server" /></td>
        <td><%# Eval("OrderNo") %></td>
        <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
        <td><%# Eval("Created") %></td>
        <td><%# Eval("Amount") %></td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**C# Code**

```
string res;
protected void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem row in LvOrders.Items)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ChkBox");
        if (cb != null)
        {
            if (cb.Checked == true)
            {
                ListViewItem item = LvOrders.Items[LvOrders.SelectedIndex];
                String c = item.FindControl("OrderNo").ToString();
                res = res + "" + c;// printing selected OrderNo
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign an ID like this.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkBx" runat="server" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:label ID="OrderNo" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("OrderNo") %>'>
        </asp:label>
    </td>
    <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
    <td><%# Eval("Created") %></td>
    <td><%# Eval("Amount") %></td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Now in code-behind

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ChkBox");
if (cb != null)
{
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        var OrderNoLabel = (Label)row.FindControl("OrderNo") ;
        res = res + "" + OrderNoLabel.Text;// printing selected OrderNo
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Naveen, but when I debug the code, even if I had selected the checkbox, it is always showing null.

Comment: showing null or unchecked? you must be binding the `asp:ListView` in `Page_Load`. If so, bind `asp:ListView` inside `!IsPostBack`

Comment: I was using two checkboxes one in the header of the table and the other one in the item template and was looking for the selected values in the header checkbox, height of stupidity. :(

Answer (score 2):

You had written `item.FindControl("OrderNo").ToString();`
But in you ASPX Page you had defined `<td><%# Eval("OrderNo") %></td>`
So, you had not defined any control and still want to find control. Hence this will cause error, the option is to  use Label, in case you want to find the control and its value.

PS: Mark as answer, if it helped

Comment: great answer Gaurav. Please elaborate the answer with some code in future +1